# htaccess 301 redirect some specific pages from old domain to new pages on new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So what i want to accomplish is:

1. i want to redirect some specific pages from old domain to some new pages on new domain and the rest of the old pages to a single page over new domain(***Note***: Dont want to redirect any of the them to homepage)
2. Also want to redirect subdomain blog.olddomain.com/tag/abc to newdomain.com/abc

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/merger/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/xyz/?$ http://newdomain.com/abc/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Right now using this above code all pages of old domain are redirecting to http://www.newdomain.com/merger

help me to fix this.

Comment: But then why are you using `category/xyz/?` in pattern?

Comment: that was the slug of a post of olddomain `[http://olddomain.com/category/xyz]` which i want to redirect to new post in new domain.`[http://newdomain.com/abc/]`

Comment: ok then keep these specific redirects above generic rule. So keep `RewriteRule ^category/xyz/?$ http://newdomain.com/abc/ [L,R=301]` below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @anubhava thank you soo much, it worked, now can you please tell me how to accomplish that 2nd point which i asked above, about subdomain part

Comment: Is that blog subdomain pointing to same direction as main site?

Comment: its not pointing anywhere, actually i bought that olddomain, and i want to restore that whole site again on another domain so thats why i am redirecting and recreating all important pages and subdomains.

Comment: But you must haves VirtualHost configuration somewhere for olds domain otherwise htaccess rules won't work